# open ball such that : $t \mapsto \operatorname{rank}( U+ tA)$ is constant where $^tU U = I_p$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

> Let $U, A  \in M_{n,p}(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $^t U U = I_p$. Prove that the function : $t \mapsto  \operatorname{rank}(U + tA)$ is constant on a neighborhood of $0$.

I have solution when $n = p$ and $U$ is invertible. To prove it we can do the following : the function $\det$ is continuous hence if there is a sequence $(t_n) \to 0$ such that $U + t_nA$ is not invertible it would mean that $\det(U+t_nA)$ but since $\det$ is continuous this is absurde since by taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get $\det(U) = 0$ which is false.

Somehow I think I need to use the same argument but in more clever way to extend the result to non-invertible and non-square matrix. Yet I don't know how to do so. One idea would be to say that a non-square matrix can be thought as a square matrix in which there are a lot of $0$, but the problem is that in this case the matrix is not invertible...

Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean a *deleted* neighbourhood of $0$ (i.e. a neighbourhood sans $0$)?

Comment: @user1551 I am really sorry I forgot an important information on the matrix $U$. It should be correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by rank-nullity theorem, it suffices to show that
$$
f(t)= \dim \ker(U+tA)
$$ is constant on a neighborhood of $0$. We find that $U^TU=I_p$ implies $\ker U =(0)$, hence $f(0)=0$. Assume to the contrary that there exists a sequence $t_n\ne 0$ converging to $0$ such that $$
f(t_n)\ge 1,\quad n\ge 1.
$$ Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset \Bbb S^{p-1}$ of unit vectors such that
$$
Ux_n+t_n Ax_n =0.
$$ Since $\Bbb S^{p-1}=\{x \in\Bbb R^p: \|x\|=1\}$ is compact, by passing to a subsequence, we may assume that $x_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x$ for some $x\in \Bbb S^{p-1}$. This implies
$$
Ux = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(Ux_n +t_nAx_n\right)=0,
$$ which leads to the contradiction to that $\ker U =(0)$. Thus $f(t) = 0$ on a neighborhood of $0$ as wanted.